# Bizarre linking error when linking base_local_planner

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building running catkin_make, but the build fails when linking base_local_planner.

I am running raspbian on raspberry pi.

I've never seen this error before. Does anyone know what might be the cause?

The Error

```
Linking CXX shared library /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libbase_local_planner.so

'.LTHUNK2' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10bad_alloc_D1Ev[boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_::~bad_alloc_()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10bad_alloc_D2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail10bad_alloc_D5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o
'.LTHUNK4' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail14bad_exception_D1Ev[boost::exception_detail::bad_exception_::~bad_exception_()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail14bad_exception_D2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail14bad_exception_D5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o
'.LTHUNK66' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_10bad_alloc_EED1Ev[boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_>::~clone_impl()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_10bad_alloc_EED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_10bad_alloc_EED5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o
'.LTHUNK67' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_10bad_alloc_EED1Ev[boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_>::~clone_impl()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_10bad_alloc_EED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_10bad_alloc_EED5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o
'.LTHUNK70' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_14bad_exception_EED1Ev[boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::bad_exception_>::~clone_impl()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_14bad_exception_EED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_14bad_exception_EED5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o
'.LTHUNK71' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_14bad_exception_EED1Ev[boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::bad_exception_>::~clone_impl()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_14bad_exception_EED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_14bad_exception_EED5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/map_grid.cpp.o
'.LTHUNK44' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEED1Ev[boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error>::~error_info_injector()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/odometry_helper_ros.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEED5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/odometry_helper_ros.cpp.o
'.LTHUNK46' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEEEED1Ev[boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >::~clone_impl()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/odometry_helper_ros.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEEEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEEEED5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/odometry_helper_ros.cpp.o
'.LTHUNK47' referenced in section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEEEED1Ev[boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >::~clone_impl()]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/odometry_helper_ros.cpp.o: defined in discarded section '.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEEEED2Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_10lock_errorEEEED5Ev]' of CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/src/odometry_helper_ros.cpp.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
base_local_planner/CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/build.make:660: recipe for target '/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libbase_local_planner.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libbase_local_planner.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5245: recipe for target 'base_local_planner/CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [base_local_planner/CMakeFiles/base_local_planner.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223297/bizarre-linking-error-when-linking-base_local_planner/) by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 363 on 2015-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed some boost libraries using `apt-get install` and that fixed it.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) with karma: 363 on 2015-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0